# Dynamically assigning IDs to tags using an EL variable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, el

I want to loop over a number of "guests" and insert an id dynanimally

```
<ui:repeat value="#{guestList}" var="guest">
    <p:inputText id="firstname_#{guest.uniqueID}" value="" label="Firstname" />
    <p:message for="firstname_#{guest.uniqueID}" />
</ui:repeat>
```

The problem is, that the `<p:message />`cannot resolve `firstname_#{guest.uniqueID}`

> javax.faces.FacesException - Cannot find component "firstname_1" in view.
>   at org.primefaces.component.message.MessageRenderer.encodeEnd(MessageRenderer.java:41)

It works without any problems if I write a constant inside the loop, and also I am sure that the variable can be resolved, as I can output it in that loop.

How can I instruct jsf or primefaces to resolve this variable?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot use EL expressions in the `id` attribute.

But you don't need to care for the uniqueness of your ids in ui:repeat. JSF does it for you. Just give your input field a "fixed" id and reference it in your `p:message`:

```html
<ui:repeat value="#{guestList}" var="guest">
    <p:inputText id="firstname" value="" label="Firstname" />
    <p:message for="firstname" />
</ui:repeat>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the guest number is a mere simplification of my problem since I need those IDs for addressing the right fields inside my backing bean. Unless there is a another way, to address my bean in another way, this isn't yet the solution to my problem. (I tried to make it more clear in my question)

Comment: It is not clear why you need the id in the backing bean. You left the value attribute blank. It should be used to bind the input to a backing bean field. Maybe that is what you need?

Comment: You are right! Now I got it: Since I am iterating through all my "guests" anyway, I can dynamically assign the value bindings in my loop. (Sorry for the confusion, but actually the problem occurs knee-deep in nested compositions)